# discord.py economy adding and subtracting into database

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making an economy command with sqlite3 (I'm new to sqlite3). I have the crime command to pick a random number from -150 (arrested) to 400. But when you run the command it will reset your money to whatever you got. Example You have 330 in the database. You run the command `>crime` and get 150. Your balance went from 330 to 150 instead of 480.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def crime(ctx):
    money = random.randrange(-150, 400)

    db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM economy WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        await ctx.send("Oh no! You do not have an account! You can create an account by typing command `>open_account`.")
    else:
        if money == 0:
            await ctx.send("Dang... The person you robbed had no money on them")
        elif money <= 0:
            await ctx.send(f"You were caught!! You were fined ${money}.")
        elif money > 5:
            await ctx.send(f"Was it all worth it? You made ${money}.")
        elif money > 15:
            await ctx.send(f"I mean at least you stole ${money}.")
        elif money > 30:
            await ctx.send(f"You stole a phone and made ${money} off of it.")
        elif money > 45:
            await ctx.send(f"You stole ${money}. Nice!")
        elif money > 60:
            await ctx.send(f"You stole everything you could grab in a car. You sold it all for ${money}.")
        elif money > 75:
            await ctx.send(f"You broke into a house and stole a tv! You made ${money} off of it.")
        elif money > 100:
            await ctx.send(f"You stole a laptop and sold it for ${money}.")
        elif money > 150:
            await ctx.send(f"You robbed a dude for his new and expensive shoes. You made ${money}.")
        elif money > 200:
            await ctx.send(f"You pushed a kid off his bike. You were able to sell it for ${money}.")
        elif money > 300:
            await ctx.send(f"You stole a car and scraped it for ${money}.")

    sql = ("UPDATE economy SET wallet = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND guild_id = ?")
    var = (money, ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.id)
    cursor.execute(sql, var)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

How would I get the 150 added to the 300?

Comment: you have to `SELECT` from database, add/subtract value in Python and `UPDATE` new value in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the result of the crime function and the money stored in the database. Do this buy getting the money in the database using a SELECT statement and casting it to an integer. Then add it and use the UPDATE statement to finally update the money.

Example :

```py
money = random.randrange(-150, 400)
db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(f"SELECT wallet FROM economy WHERE user_id = {ctx.author.id}")
OldMoney = int(cursor[0]["wallet"])
NewMoney = OldMoney + money
sql = f"UPDATE economy SET wallet = {NewMoney} WHERE user_id = {ctx.author.id}"
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.close()
cursor.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Best to always parameterize Python values in SQL queries. F-strings is just new form of insecure, string interpolation. See [SQLite3 parameter docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Consider capturing `wallet` info in the opening query (and be consistent in use of parameters):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT user_id, wallet FROM economy WHERE guild_id = ?", ctx.guild.id)
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Then at end, add accumulate money in wallet:

```
sql = ("UPDATE economy SET wallet = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND guild_id = ?")
var = (result[1] + money, ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.id)
```